# Unable to fetch django view data in react component

Tags: javascript, django

I have just created simple **django view** as:

```
def index(request):
    name = "Dude" 
    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html' {'user':json.dumps(name)})
```

Now i need to just get "user" in reactjs.
My **index.js** is:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <h1>{ user }</h1>
      </div>);
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-app'));`
```

In which "react-app" is Id of element in my django html template. Now, please help me, i am not getting what i need to do as i am new in reactjs. its compulsory to use jquery to come out this problem? please guide me.
Thank You.

Comment: Try with `{{ user }}`

Comment: i have also tried with {{user}}, but getting fail to get data

Comment: How are you getting data from index.html to index.js?

Comment: what error exactly you are getting ?

Comment: error is "ReferenceError: user is not defined"

Comment: Please guide me. I am stucked here that how to access " user "  in react Component?